# How to search for a string and append to each occurance in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, append

Currently I am working on a project and I am trying to see which String method would be most appropriate to use or how to approach this. I am trying to prepend a string to each occurrence of this specific string. For example, I am extracting HTML and for each `/img/image1.png` I find I want to append a url to it.

However, there are images that are already like that for example `www.anylink.com/img/image2.png` which do not need appending but are in the string in which I pulled. I looked at `replaceAll()` method but not sure if this allows for appending in replacement and also not sure if I need regex to search for instances where only `/img/` exists(no url) and not the full url since only local hosted images I want to append to. I am looking for some suggestions as I am not sure how to begin this code after research.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you actually mean prepend? Because it doesn't make much sense to add url *after* `/img/image1.png` (`/img/image1.pngwww.example.com`).
If the images are in html as `src="/img/image1.png"`, you could do replace for `"/img/`

Comment: @Henri Viik I did mean prepend, I am sorry about that. Forgot to say append to the front of. I cannot simply do that since some images already have url/img/image1.png and some don't. That would wrongly affect those that already have a url to be urlurl/img/imag1.png wouldn't it?

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls

Comment: @Pshemo Due to the current structure of the program I would not want to use jsoup as I already extracted the url with different methods and extracted the url as well, I just need to prepend. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method replaceAll() in String is enough for what you need.

You just need to write the correct regular expression.

If you write some examples, I can suggest the regex.

For example something like:

```
System.out.println("<div><img src=\"/test/this.png\" /></div>".replaceAll("src=\"/(.*)\"", "src=\"www.google.com$1\""));
```

Comment: The thing is the string has A LOT of different HTML like that so should still work correct? Since I will parse through many <img > in that string.Also, I am trying to learn regex atm to only go through /img/image1.png (so basically no url before them). Will this be using regex? Also, I will write some example tonight. Should I reply here or make a new post? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Ok. My solution is acceptable for small html. If you need to parse a big page, you should use an html parser.

Comment: The only problem with the replaceAll is that you need to load the all html in one string. Unless you are able to read blocks of the page.

Comment: I already have all the HTML in one string :) .Would I still need regex to exactly match images with /img/image1.png format (meaning no url behind it)? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried the regex I wrote ? It seems that your use case is not so difficult and so that regex could be enough

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I working on this project. I tried this regex and it worked with the help of a friend. However I still need to study up on it and I will try yours in my local computer to see the differences. In your experience would there have been any? `("src=\"([a-zA-Z0-9/\\.\\-]*)\"","src=\""+url+"$1\"")`

Comment: For this project I parse every url to simply start with www.domain.com before adding it on the replaceAll method. Since this is for a report hosted on a different site to which I know the format of the image and the url itself. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: what I meant is that, based on the description of your post, there are url with a complete path http://... and url with only the path /something/else. If I understand, you want to add the http:// to the urls that do not already have it. It seems to me that your regex does not make any distinctions between urls with and without http://